# TCP socket will not stop receiving data from Android client, getting series of '\0'

Tags: sockets, tcp

When my Android client connects to the server (which is written in C#), the server will receive series of '\0'. Even if I close the Android application or disconnect the phone, the server still receives this data.

I tested my server with a C# client and there was no problem on the server.

This is my server code in C#:

```
private void listen_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                  SocketType.Stream,
                                  ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        // Bind to local IP Address...
        _socket.Bind(ipLocal);
        // Start listening...
        _socket.Listen(4);
        // Create the call back for any client connections...
        _socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
    }

}

// This is the call back function, which will be invoked when a client is connected
public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    try
    {
        Socket workerSocket = _socket.EndAccept(asyn);
        _socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_clientCount);
        m_workerSocketList.Add(workerSocket);
        clientsName.Add("$unknown$");
        if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox1.Items.Clear(); foreach (string name in clientsName) listBox1.Items.Add(name); }));
        }
        ArrayList rthreadParams = new ArrayList();
        rthreadParams.Add(workerSocket);
        rthreadParams.Add(m_clientCount);
        Thread rThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WaitForData));
        rThread.Start(rthreadParams);
        rThread.Join();

    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
    }
}

public class SocketPacket
{
    public Socket m_currentSocket;
    public int m_clientNumber;
    public SocketPacket(Socket socket, int clientNumber)
    {
        m_currentSocket = socket;
        m_clientNumber = clientNumber;
    }
    public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
}
public void WaitForData(object param)
{
    try
    {
        Socket soc = (Socket)((ArrayList)param)[0];
        int clientNumber = (int)((ArrayList)param)[1];
        if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
        {
            pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
        }
        SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket(soc, clientNumber);

        soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                         SocketFlags.None, pfnWorkerCallBack, theSocPkt);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
    }
}
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        int iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
        char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
        System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
        String szData = new String(chars);
        szData = szData.Replace("\0", "");

        // doing some work with szData

        ArrayList t_Params = new ArrayList();
        t_Params.Add(socketData.m_currentSocket);
        t_Params.Add(socketData.m_clientNumber);
        WaitForData(t_Params);

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {

    }
}
```

and this is the Android client code:

```
    try
    {
        InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.50.11", 2001);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(sa,4000);


        OutputStream dos = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(dos);
        out.write("hello");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(appTag, e.toString());
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I believe if a connection is closed and you try to read from that port, it rads nulls

Comment: @ColeJohnson It would be truly astonishing if it didn't return an error or throw an exception.

Comment: All connections are just reading from ports. Prob prob exists because it's android

Comment: thanks.I,m noob in socket programming and also my English is weak. Plz explain more clearly!. server will begin receiving data when socket connects to server in android and will not stop. and as I said there is no such problem with .NET client.

Comment: I'm getting crazy going through the source code over and over again.
Where is the problem? in client side or server?

Comment: @ColeJohnson You appear to be just posting wild guesses here. Some fact-based information would be somewhat more useful.

Comment: @EJP I'm not too proficient in this area but I know a little and that is what I was told: if you read from a port without receiving data you will receive random data or nulls

Answer (score 0):

I created another client in python with this code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOC_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",2001))
s.send("hello!")
```

and there was not such problem in server.
only when I create a socket in android, that problem occurres.

Where is the problem??